# Поехала верстка в профиле во вкладке "Реакции"

Tags: дефект, дизайн, профиль-участника

[image: Скриншот 1]

[image: Скриншот 2]

Проверял на браузерах:

- Vivaldi 2.10.1745.26 (Stable channel) (64 бит)
- Firefox 72.0.1 (64-битный)

Comment: Странно что на мете почти нормально.

Comment: Немного тоже поехало. А у тебя прям каждая буква на новой строке О_о

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, не сказал бы https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSxy6.png

Comment: Нужно будет из дома проверить, может из-за большого разрешения такие проблемы

Comment: @insolor, у меня лучше. Мета: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf3Ap.png, сайт: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fcy8.png.